# Fetch Django models in list view to show both

Tags: python, django, listview, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I have this models:

Article:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField(
        max_length=5,
        primary_key=True,
        validators=[MinLengthValidator(5)]
    )
    ean = models.CharField(
        max_length=13,
        unique=True,
        validators=[MinLengthValidator(13)]
    )
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'Article',
        related_name='children',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
...
```

and ArticleTranslations:

```
class ArticleTranslation(models.Model):
    LANGUAGE_CHOICES = (
        (settings.ENGLISH, _("english")),
        (settings.FRENCH, _("french")),
        (settings.GERMAN, _("german")),
        (settings.ITALIAN, _("italian")),
        (settings.PORTUGUESE, _("portuguese")),
        (settings.SPANISH, _("spanish")),
    )
    article = models.ForeignKey(
        'Article',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='translations',
    )
```

I need to return both, combined to show the 2 items in a Django Templates HTML for. Need to have the item and the foreign key and see it in the same iterations. I wanna do it with the methods of the class List View and django, and not doing something bad.
I have this ListView:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = (Article.objects
                    .all()
                    .prefetch_related('translations')
                    .order_by('-sku'))

        print(queryset)

        return queryset
```

And in my HTML, need to show the foreign key values:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% for article in article_list %}
        <div class="container">
            <h2>{{ article.translations.NEED_TO_SHOW_THAT_PARAMETER }}</h2>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}


{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: `{{ article.translations.all }}` is a list of the `translations` in your template (it's the equivalent of `article.translations.all()` in python code). So you can loop through that, e..g `{% for translation in article.translations.all %}` and display whatever you want in the loop, e.g. `{{ translation.id }}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view you're already getting right data. So in your template you can simply loop through the `Article` objects and it's foreign key values (as they can be accessed using `related_name`)

you're using `{% for article in article_list %}` so I believe you have `context_object_name = 'article_list'` set in your views.

I'm guessing extra fields for `translations` model which you're probably wanting to access. If your model looks something like this:

```
class ArticleTranslation(models.Model):
    LANGUAGE_CHOICES = (
        (settings.ENGLISH, _("english")),
        (settings.FRENCH, _("french")),
        (settings.GERMAN, _("german")),
        (settings.ITALIAN, _("italian")),
        (settings.PORTUGUESE, _("portuguese")),
        (settings.SPANISH, _("spanish")),
    )
    article = models.ForeignKey(
        'Article',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='translations',
    )
    language = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES)
```

Then in your template you can do:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% for article in article_list %}
        <div class="container">
            {% for object in article.translations.all %}
                <h2>Chosend language - {{ object.language }}</h2>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Explanation:
`article.translations.all` will give you all translations for one `article`, using this you can get the field value